# Purpose of async methods when implementing a web controller?

Tags: async-await, httpwebrequest

When implementing an api only used within a web controllers actions, say a repository with a FindById-method, is there any good reason for implementing it as asynchronous or could it even be better to just stick with plain old sync methods? I'm thinking that since all web requests are async in nature already it wouldn't do much good having internal methods async as well? I mean the request is already on it's own thread and the caller won't be blocked even if my internal server side methods are called synchronous? The overhead of having it async could perhaps even make the request unnecessary slow? What is the best practice here?

Comment: *"the request is already on it's own thread"* - And if it's waiting on a blocking call then it holds onto that thread, leaving it idle and unable to be used by anything else.  Whereas awaiting an async call allows the server to use that thread for other work, such as handling other requests which themselves will then await async calls.  If your site is very low-traffic (e.g. personal use) then there likely wouldn't be a difference.  For higher traffic situations you don't want to block your threads.

Comment: Ahh good point. Didn't think of that. How much do we gain by reusing threads like this? I mean the CPU would have to do all the work non-the-less. Wouldn't re-using threads also slow down all other threads so that the overall time would be roughly the same? I guess this could avoid some requests to time out at least. I'm just guessing here. And what about the overhead of kicking off a new thread? It sound like this approach is only preferred when having lots and lots of requests? When only having moderate traffic this seem to only worsen the performance slightly.

Comment: It’s certainly possible to slow down other threads, in which case the overall system is too taxed and needs to be scaled out.  But if threads are blocked then they’re idle, not using the CPU.  The idea here is that if the system is waiting on I/O (disk, network, etc.) then async allows the thread to be used by the CPU to perform other tasks while it waits.  So the web server can do the same job while consuming fewer threads and making more efficient CPU use.